# Duplicated link table between User and Role using Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

On configuring Identity on net6.0, I've used a custom User and custom Role entities derived from Identity ones.

Everything was great, working fine till I've tried to list the Roles of my Users.

The reality is that the system now has 2 tables: UserRoles (created and maintained by Identity) and another one, a join table between User and Role, called RoleUser, created by convention by having a navigation property on each entity.

[image: er diagram]

Questions are:
1.How to unmess this?
2.Can I keep using the working Roles and still use derived classes for my entities?
3.Ideally solve this duality, remove the "RoleUser" table and make everything work seamlessly.

Been trying to fix it by forcing the mapping I want on ModelBuilder:

```
builder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
                .WithMany(e => e.Users)
                .UsingEntity(
                    "UserRoles",
                    l => l.HasOne(typeof(Role)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("RoleId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Role.Id)),
                    r => r.HasOne(typeof(User)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(User.Id)),
                    j => j.HasKey("UserId", "RoleId"));
```

And deriving a "UserRole" from `IdentityUserRole<long>` and pointing the framework to the right direction, but all I get is:

InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'UserRoles' for entity type 'UserRole' since it is being used for entity type 'UserRoles (Dictionary<string, object>)' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'UserRole' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'UserRoles'.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are Duplicated join tables between roles and users, If you don't configure `builder.Entity<User>()..` by yourself, Does identity will generate Duplicated tables?